# Is it possible to get an "initialized and read but never altered" warning?

Tags: c++

Question is pretty much in the title.

I'd be happy with something that works just for fundamental types.

(Obviously I wouldn't want this for anything declared e.g. `const`, but surely any existing tool would handle that case.)

**UPDATE**: Sample program

```
#include <algorithm>

class ShipmentManager
{
  public: void shipBananasToCustomer(int size) { /* ... */ }
};

class CustomerAccount
{
  private:

    ShipmentManager shipmentManager;

    int bananasInStock = 0;
    int bananasOrderedByCustomer = 0;
    int bananasShippedToCustomer = 0;
    
  public:

    void gotOrderForBananas(int size) { bananasOrderedByCustomer += size; }

    void receivedShipmentOfBananas(int size) { bananasInStock += size; }

    void shipAvailableBananasToCustomer()
    { 
      const int bananasToShip = std::min(
        bananasInStock,
        bananasOrderedByCustomer - bananasShippedToCustomer);

      shipmentManager.shipBananasToCustomer(bananasToShip);
    }
};
```

The trouble here is that `CustomerAccount::shipAvailableBananasToCustomer` never updates `bananasShippedToCustomer`, so the customer will just continue to get all available bananas shipped to him forever.

We can infer from the code that there's no way for the value of `bananasShippedToCustomer` to change from zero, but it's not marked `const`.  I'd like to get a warning about this.

Of course in general this probably has to come from static analysis or something since the method definitions of `CustomerAccount` could be spread across a header and multiple source files.  That said, I'd also be fairly happy with a compile-time check that only fires if it happens to be able to see all the method definitions in a class at once.

Comment: Looks like you are asking about `-Wunused-variable`: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html

Comment: It would help if you showed a program that should trigger the warning you want.

Comment: _Initialized and read_ sound suspicious, however. It makes me think of `int x = 3; std::cin >> x;` which _is_ altering the value of `x` with respect to the value you initialized it to. Therefore, as @cigien suggested, give us a small example.

Comment: @NathanOliver: That looks like it works for locals, thanks.  Do you know any way of doing the same for members?  (Of course I'm aware that that's a more involved problem.)

Comment: No, I have not seen a warning for unused member variables.  That could be very hard to solve as you would have to check the behavior of everything that has access to the variables while local variables are easy as you know the scope they could be altered in.

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis: I don't follow.  In your example, x gets passed as a non-const reference to `istream::operator>>`, so it can be assumed that it has been altered.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Yes, in general the final check would have to happen at (or after) link time if you don't want false negatives.  However, I'd be happy with something with false negatives if it could just say, "Hey, when I was handling this compilation unit I was able to see everything that could possibly access this member, and it's assigned and read but never changed."

Comment: Do a reference on your banana :) i.e. `void shipBananasToCustomer(int& size)`

Comment: @DanielMcLaury, I was referring to _Initialized and read_. What is _read_? For me, reading `x` means `cin >> x;` or similar, for instance.

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis: I would call that *writing* `x`, since it alters the value of `x`.  To me, `reading` would mean using the value stored in `x`.

Comment: So you want a warning for `int main() { int n = 42; cout << n; }`?

Comment: @cigien: In principle, yes, although of course what I'm hoping to be warned of is something more like the code example I gave.

Comment: I understand. I was just checking, and trying to come up with a minimal example :) fwiw, I don't think I've ever heard of such a warning. Not that that means it doesn't exist of course.

Comment: @DanielMcLaury, fair enough; I was reading _read_ from the perspective the executable, which uses `cin` to _read_ something from keyboard.